# WATIR : how to set a checkbox inside a label

Tags: watir

How can I check that checkbox using WATIR

```html
<label title="Active-DC Cloud Management" class="custom-checkbox ng-scope folderSelector"> 
<span class="customCheckBox icn" ng-disabled="cDisabled"> 
<input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-model="model" ng-change="changeCallback({$event:$event})" ng-disabled="cDisabled" type="checkbox"> 
</span> Active-DC Cloud Management<!-- ngIf: cFoldertype == 'ASP' || cFoldertype == 'VCE' || cFoldertype == 'CPL' --> 
</label>
```

I have tried using the following but that doesn't work

`@browser.label(:text,'Active-DC Cloud Management').parent.click`

Here is more of the HTMl code

```html
<li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="subfolder in subfolder.subFolders" ng-class="{expandButton:subfolder.hasSubFolders,plus:subfolder.hasSubFolders, disabled:subfolder.folderAccess == 'NONE', selected:selectedFolderIdsArray.indexOf(subfolder.folderId) !== -1}" id="1001665955" ftpath="HOME\Order_12329753" ftname="Order_12329753" ftlevel="2" fttype="ORDER" ftaccess="VIEW">
<a name="&amp;lpos=my : 263" href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="toggleSelectFolder(subfolder.folderId,subfolder.fullFolderPath)" style="padding-left: 28px" data-this-tree="thisTree" complete-folder-stack="completeFolderStack" folder-data-ftype="subfolder.folderType">
<span class="expandCollapseIcon ng-hide" style="left: 15px" ng-show="subfolder.hasSubFolders" ng-click="expander($event,subfolder.folderAccess); ajaxLoad($event,subfolder)">&nbsp;</span>
<label class="custom-checkbox ng-scope folderSelector">
<span class="customCheckBox icn" ng-disabled="cDisabled">
<input class="ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-model="model" ng-change="changeCallback({$event:$event})" ng-disabled="cDisabled" type="checkbox"></span>Order_12329753<!-- ngIf: cFoldertype == 'ASP' || cFoldertype == 'VCE' || cFoldertype == 'CPL' --></label></a>
<ul class="subfolder"><!-- ngRepeat: subfolder in subfolder.subFolders --></ul></li>
```

Comment: Maybe `@browser.label(:text,'Active-DC Cloud Management').checkbox.set`?

Comment: @Justin I got the same error as before `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`

Comment: The error says the element is not visible. Have you made sure the checkbox is visible when you try to click it?

Comment: Yesy sir. I can actually click/unclick the checkbox manually right before I run the command

Comment: OK i figured this part out it seems like the div that contains all this code is set to be disabled (not invisible) so because of that I can not use the regular functions associated with the checkbox element but I can use the fire_event method of the browser to click on the checkbox                            `b.input(:xpath,"//label[@title='Active-DC Cloud Management']/span/input").fire_event :click`

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured this part out it seems like the div that contains all this code is set to be disabled (not invisible) so because of that I can not use the regular functions associated with the checkbox element but I can use the fire_event method of the browser to click on the checkbox                            `b.input(:xpath,"//label[@title='Active-DC Cloud Management']/span/input").fire_event :click`